# Shatter object with rigidbody physics with constraints (cell fracture)

Tags: physics, constraints

I'm having this problem with shattering my object following this quick tips video of Gleb Alexandrov:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJFE2pb0Ri4

I am trying to achieve the 3rd effect.

So I set a particle system and used the cell fracture addon, but my object pieces look kind of different from my original object, and they are moved to the next layer in my blender file. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I can't seem to finish the animation.

Here is my blend file:

[image]

Comment: Well, it looks like your numerous WALL.002_cell.* elements are out of position, and have no physics elements to them.  How did they go from being pieces of a wall to being scattered rubble?  Existing in the next layer is perfectly normal for the cell fracture addon (it helps you work with them without tripping over all the other objects in the scene)

Comment: Yes,the elements are completely out of position. I tried applying the object rotation and scale before using the cell fracture add-on and still got the same result.